# Как получить определеные значения масива?

Tags: php

есть массив

```
'genre' => 
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'жанр</td><td>
            <span itemprop="genre"><a href="/lists/m_act%5Bgenre%5D/14/">мультфильм</a>, <a href="/lists/m_act%5Bgenre%5D/3/">боевик</a>, <a href="/lists/m_act%5Bgenre%5D/6/">комедия</a>, <a href="/lists/m_act%5Bgenre%5D/11/">семейный</a></span>' (length=298)
  1 => string '<a href="/lists/m_act%5Bgenre%5D/14/">мультфильм</a>, <a href="/lists/m_act%5Bgenre%5D/3/">боевик</a>, <a href="/lists/m_act%5Bgenre%5D/6/">комедия</a>, <a href="/lists/m_act%5Bgenre%5D/11/">семейный</a>' (length=234)
  2 => string 'мультфильм' (length=20)
  3 => string 'боевик' (length=12)
  4 => string 'комедия' (length=14)
  5 => string 'семейный' (length=16)
```

мне надо получить все значения кроме первых двух

Comment: в чём проблема и в чём, конкретнее, вопрос? Вам нужен массив, состоящий из всех элементов данного, кроме первых двух? См. [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [array_slice($arr, $n)](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого удобно воспользоваться функцией `array_slice()`

```
<?php
$arr = ['genre' => ['жанр', 'мультфильм', 'боевик', 'комедия', 'семейный']];
$arr = array_slice($arr['genre'], 2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```